# Delay in requesting data using AXIOS / React while Postman is quick

Tags: reactjs, performance, axios

I have a sizeable react application pulling data using AXIOS. I noticed that for some of my queries it takes long to get the data in the application itself (using axios say ~30 secs) but it's very quick when I execute the same query in Postman (~300 ms).

When analyzing a bit more i noticed the delay seems to be in the server receiving the request. I'm currently using AXIOS POST of an array (~100 IDs) in order to get the respective records for each ID in the array.

My question is - what may be causing this delay in React/Axios vs. Postman and how to solve this?

Some of the relevant code:

Triggering the request

`dispatch(fetchClausesByIDArr(clauses))`

Redux action

```
export function fetchClausesByIDArr(clauses) {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchClausesPending());
      axios.post('/c/clauses', {
        clauses: clauses
      })
      .then(function(res) {

        // further dispatching the clauses once received - there is a delay right before this

      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        dispatch(fetchClausesError(err));
      })
  }
}
```

Server (Express) handling

```
const getClausesByIDArr = async (req, res) => {

    // Receiving this request in Express seems delayed
    const body = req.body

    if (!body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'You must provide a clause',
        })
    }

    await ClauseModel.find( { _id: body.clauses}, (err, clauses) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: err })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: clauses })
    })
}
```

Comment: not related to your problem but you don't need to use `async-await` because you are using callback version of `.find` function. Just remove the `async` and `await` from the `getClausesByIDArr` function

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm experiencing a very similar issue!

Comment: The cause ended up being the rendering in React. I am rendering a large list of complex components, following the data pull.